# How to add missing getters and setters to existing entity (#Shopware 6, #b2bsellers, #b2bsellers-suite)

Tags: shopware6

I am tasked to make the [B2Bsellers plugin](https://www.b2b-sellers.com/en/) work for our use case.
I need to access data from EmployeePermissionTranslationEntity. The plugin has not defined a getter for the field i need to access.

I can see that the data exists though debugging, but the getter is not defined. How can I extend this entity and manually add the getter though my own plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Entity` class defines a magic getter method https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/v6.4.15.2/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/Entity.php#L44

so you should have access to it with `$employeePermissionTranslationEntity->propertyName`

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe tell me which data you want to get from EmployeePermissionTranslationEntity

Currently you only can get the name.
This is the only available translation for EmployeePermission

Comment: I'm trying to access 'B2bEmployeePermissionId ' the foreign key

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).